# An http request in a custom validator in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a custom ActiveRecord validator which should do a network/http request as one of the validation checks. Whether or not it does it, depends on the arguments passed to it. When it does it, a request might fail, take a lot of time, a remote server might be down, etc...

Thus it should be sent asynchronously. And probably a user shouldn't wait for it to finish. Because if a server is down, how long will a user have to wait?

At the same time, my validator is mandatory and as long as it's being verified, a model can't be saved in a db.

Therefore, how would I go about implementing that? Validation in ActiveRecord in synchronous.

Answer (score 4):

You would ideally should keep it asynchronous. You will have to rethink the whole flow for the user.

My suggestion would be to use a queuing system. Let the user save his/her account and show them a message that their account is pending validation and will be informed via email.

Meanwhile, push the data to the queue, process the records in the queue one by one (meaning, make the request to the server) and validate. Based on the validation activate or de-activate the account and send an email to the user.

Comment: why by queue and not by sidekiq or the the like?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Sidekiq also uses queues internally. It's something that you could use to solve your purpose

Comment: @Kona: what's the difference between "queue" and "sidekiq"?